# Watching property changes on Dart polymer-element

Tags: dart, polymer

Is there a way to watch property changes on Dart polymer-element as described in [Change watchers](http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.html#change-watchers) section?  I tried adding `void myattributeChanged(String oldValue)` method but it does not get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem that `propertynameChanged()` mechanism is supported by Dart polymer.

Dart `CustomElement` has lifecycle methods, one of which is

`void attributeChanged(String name, String oldValue, String newValue)`

But, according to this [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12719), the method is not invoked at the moment :(

I worked this around for now by using

`ObservableMixin.Stream`'s property `<List<ChangeRecord>> get changes` and simply listening for changes on this getter:

`changes.listen((changeRecords) { ... });`

Answer (score 1):

this problem was fixed a while ago

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: I don't understand what this downvote and comment is about. This was a bug in Dart that is now fixed.